# Apache mod_rewrite not linking properly

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

am new to PHP, apache, been trying to do the mod_rewrite thing this is code
it is supposed to rewrite from `localhost/main/teacher/index.php?subj=departments` to `localhost/main/staff/department`. 
if I type the link localhost/main/staff/departments it works but 
Whenever I click on the link it gives `localhost/main/staff/index.php?subj=department`.

Here is my `.htaccess` code:

```
RewriteEngine On
Rewrite ^staff/(.+)$    teacher/index.php?subj=$1   [NC, L]
```

Comment: `mod_rewrite` has nothing to do with PHP, it's done by the Apache webserver.

Comment: The rules you posted certainly will _not_ create the outcome you state. Maybe you are looking at a cached result? Try making a "deep reload" or clearing your browsers cache.

Comment: will change the title but how do I fix these

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you should have in your `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^staff/(.+)$    teacher/index.php?subj=$1 [NC]
```

Note the second line starts with `RewriteRule`, not `Rewrite`.
Also, you need to remove the *L* flag from this rule.

You can read more about the flags [here](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html).

I wish someone would improve the answer and explain in detail why `NC, L` doesn't work, while `NC` alone works.

Comment: changed the rewrite to RewriteRule but still same error, even cleared browser cache

Comment: Browser cache has nothing to do with it, we are tinkering with how apache adresses the request. Did you remove the flag? Is there anything else in your `.htaccess` file?